# Camera node does not publish compressed image when launched in a composable container

Tags: ros2, camera, launch-file

I'm working on a launch file to launch the [v4l2_camera node](https://gitlab.com/boldhearts/ros2_v4l2_camera/-/tree/rolling?ref_type=heads). I first launched it as a normal node, which worked as expected - it publishes a raw image, and also uses the image transport plugins to publish compressed images.

```
Node(
        package='v4l2_camera',
        executable='v4l2_camera_node',
        name='camera_node',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'camera_info_url': camera_info_dynamic_path},
                    camera_config_dynamic_path]),
```

Next, I decided to launch it as a composable container. This also works, but only the raw image is published, and there is no compressed image topic.

```
ComposableNodeContainer(
        name='camera_container',
        namespace='',
        package='rclcpp_components',
        executable='component_container',
        output='screen',
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            ComposableNode(
                package='v4l2_camera',
                plugin='v4l2_camera::V4L2Camera',
                name='camera_node',
                namespace='',
                parameters=[{'camera_info_url': camera_info_dynamic_path},
                            camera_config_dynamic_path],
                extra_arguments=[{'use_intra_process_comms': True}],
            ),
        ]),
```

How do I fix this? I would like to run the camera node and the image transport plugins within the container.

Additional information:
I've installed v4l2_camera using apt-get, and not from source. I'm using ROS 2 Humble.